# Normal Curvature $κ_n(p, v)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be the embedded torus with parametrization $σ(θ, ϕ) =
((2 + \cos θ) \cos ϕ,(2 + \cos θ) \sin ϕ,\sin θ)$.

The first and the second fundamental forms of $σ$ are
$dθ^2 + (2 + \cos θ)^
2
dϕ^2$
and $dθ^2 + (2 + \cos θ) \cos θdϕ^2$

Let $p = (1, 0, 0)$ be a point on the torus.

Find the normal curvature $κ_n(p, v)$ in the direction of the tangent vector
$v = (0, 3, 2) ∈ T_pS$.

I'm really lost on what to do, any hints/solutions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you include in your post your definition of normal curvature $\kappa_n(p,v)$?